# What is the use of the 'instance' block property of the i3bar

Tags: window-manager, i3

I'm trying to make sense of why the 'instance' block property would be of any use.  In the:

[manpages](http://manpages.org/i3blocks) its merely listed.

[github page](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks) its described as one of "two keys used by i3bar to identify a block" (the other being 'name').

[i3wm docs pages](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3bar-protocol.html#_blocks_in_detail) it says that"i3bar completely ignores the name and instance field. Make sure to also specify an instance(string)entry where appropriate".

If 'instance' is identificatory only, then why isn't 'name' enough?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on [i3wm.org](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3bar-protocol.html):

```
 "name": "ethernet",
 "instance": "eth0",
```

So you could have multiple ethernet or disk blocks with the instance identifying the device or mount point.

Comment: why not two names: "ethernet-0" and "ethernet-1"?